# How to use PropertyGrid in Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit with cascade properties?

Tags: wpf, propertygrid, xceed

I wanna use the [PropertyGrid](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid) to modify a certain property of an object loaded from json. But in my situation, some properties are instances of a class, which also has it own properties.
I've tried to customize the editors to show those sub-properties:

```
<xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="SystemParameter">
     <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Button Command="ExpandCommand" CommandParameter="{Binding Value}">...</Button>
          </DataTemplate>
     </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
</xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>

var win = new MainWindow();
win.SetSelectedObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Parameter.ToString()));
win.ShowDialog();
```

It works but I cannot commit the modification to the first-level window. As a result, if one changed a sub-property, I cannot save this modification.

My question is:
How to use the [PropertyGrid] with cascade properties?
Is my solution right? If yes, how to save the modifications to sub-properties?